# MySQL clone a table, prune some data and then hotswap their names

Tags: mysql, ruby, copy, clone

We have a 8 million row MySQL table.  We want to prune about 2m rows from it, remove some outdated indexes and add new ones.  To achieve almost no downtime, our plan is to create a clone of the table (and lock the original), run a script (Ruby) to prune the data that we don't need anymore and finally add the new indexes.  Then we would put up the maintenance page on the web app, swap their names (by renaming the tables) and restart the app.

Is this the best way to achieve our final results? Any other tips/suggestions from people that have some something similar to this before?  Whats the best way (super cool secret mysql cmds) to clone the table? Best/quickiest way to mass delete rows?

Comment: How long does it take to execute your current script?  Any idea?

Comment: Trying to get a staging server up to time the script, but Amazon EC2 is giving me capacity errors

Answer (score 2):

1. All references use a view, not reading directly from `old_table`
2. Create new_table
3. Select desired records into `new_table`, ***don't bring along records records to be deleted***
4. Index `new_table`
5. Update view, replace `old_table` references with `new_table`
6. Rename `old_table`

Deal with old_table when you want.

The real problem is new data during the transition process, which generally means downtime.  Hopefully, you can just disable the ability to add data rather than take the entire site down.

Comment: There may be a way to do this all in straight SQL, too, if you want more speed...

Comment: Why use views? could you please go into more detail

Comment: @Jose Fernandez: Because you can change the table(s) referenced by a view at will; existing references aren't broken while you migrate between the old & new tables because the view encapsulates.